# Button in my-account to allow the user to set his membership on pause

Tags: php, woocommerce, membership

The only choice for the user in his membership area is to cancel his membership.
I want to add a toggle button in "my-account>membership" to allow the user to set his membership on "paused" / "active".
I found nothing on woocommerce pages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If others don't understand the question that is because they don't know nothing about Woocommerce Membership, so they will not be able to help me.
I don't have code to produce and that is why I ask the question.
I don't even know if a hook exist to do what I want to achieve.